# How to run PGadmin as service in windows server?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am able to run PGadmin version 4.4 as a desktop application. Is it possible to run the PGadmin as a service in windows so I can access the PGadmin web portal as a different user.

This is needed for the automation purposes.

Thanks
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

run the following from admin cmd prompt:

```
sc.exe create PGAdmin4 binpath= "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\bin\pgAdmin4.exe"
```

please ensure the "binpath" is correct for your environment

Comment: This does not work (on my system) as the service needs to long to startup. What can be done about this?